# If I delete openenterprise module from drupal module folder site is collapse

Tags: 7

I am wrongly paste the open enterprise module in drupal module folder. If I try to delete that folder total site is collapsed. How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to rebuild the registry. The simplest solution is to use Drush and [Registry Rebuild](http://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild). There's also instructions on that page in case you can't use Drush or the command line.